# Can't get div to be beside other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So im having some trouble getting this div to be next to another div.

Since this is kina hard to just ask straight up i made a short video explaining the problem so you guys can see what im talking about. I think its an easy fix im just missing something simple. I am a rather new coder so if you guys can help me out that'd be awesome! Thank you! Below i have links to the video, the code, and a image of the website just incase it helps in any way. Thanks!!!

```
VIDEO:https://youtu.be/rAYbNX8mYFI
HTML: http://pastebin.com/5m32NDJk
CSS: http://pastebin.com/tsVFaPux
IMAGE: http://imgur.com/a/iRWqO

#infosection{
width: 1024px;
height: 285px;
margin: auto;
display: block;
}

#title{
font-family: effra;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 12px;
color: #ffa200;
float: left;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 50px;
clear: both;
}

#name{
font-family: effra;
font-weight: bold;
color: #dfdfdf;
font-size: 30px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 30px;
float: left;
clear: both;

}

#info{
font-family: effra;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
color: black;
float: left;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-left: 50px;
width: 286px;
clear: both;
}


#name2{
font-family: effra;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
font-size: 30px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-top: 30px;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

#infotwo{
float: left;

}

#infoone{
float: left;
}


#info2{
font-family: effra;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
color: black;
float: left;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-left: 100px;
width: 552px;
clear: both;
float: left;


}




#togglediv1{
font-family: effra;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
color:  ;
padding-top: 42px;
padding-left: 100px;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
}

#togglediv2{
font-family: effra;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
color: ;
padding-top: 42px;
padding-left: 100px;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;

}

#togglediv3{
font-family: effra;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
color: ;
padding-top: 42px;
padding-left: 100px;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;

}



li {
  color: grey;
 font: effra;
 font-weight: bold;
 list-style-type: none;
  }

a:hover { 
color: #aaaaaa;
cursor: pointer;
}



.active, .active-start{
  color: orange;

}

.display{
  display: none;
}

 .display-start{
 display: block;
 }

 #text{
 display:block;
  }
```

Bonues question: The video wont play when you press the play button. If you see something wrong, would be appreciated if youf let me know. Thanks!

**EDIT: The solution might not be as simple as a float left somewhere, i might have  to much padding somewhere.

** i see i should paste code here, working on it

Comment: Post your code here, not in external links.

Comment: You can make an executable example here using [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You need to explain the problem here, not in a video.

Comment: create 2 main divs, one with width 30% another 70%. make them display inline-block. wrap these two main div with one that will have full page width. gice them border to see if they are next to each other. then fill them out with your content. do not use floats. if you use float the third div below them has to have clear: both in css

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem in putting two div side by side, then you can apply style with "float: left" along with "width:50%" for each div.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have so many set widths and heights in the children elements of `#infotwo`.

To solve it not very well, add this code:

```
#infoone {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

#infotwo {
  float: left;
  width: 67%;
}
```

This will fill the 1024px width. The better way to fix this issue is to not use fixed widths or heights in `#infotwo`.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stLceja4/)

Comment: Okay ill probably go back through and clean it up in the near future. When i do so and in your fiddle, it shoves the player and footer way to the right? What would be best way to get that back over where it belongs

Comment: That's because the frame that the result is displayed is not 1080px.